# Lua: If a number is between 1 and 20

Tags: if-statement, lua, comparison

I wanted to *check* if a number is between 1 and 20, this is what I am using:

```
for x=1,20 do
  if x == 10 then
    print(x)
  end
end
```

The problem is that, it prints the number 10 instead of printing `true` or

`1
2
3
..` am I doing something wrong here? If so, what’s it? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want to check mutiple numbers, or just one like this :

```
my_number = 10
if my_number >= 1 and my_number <= 20 then
    print 'it is!'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're telling it to print `x` when `x` is `10`, so it can only print `10`. It's doing exactly as you asked of it.

But what you really want is:

```
if x >= 1 and x <= 20
   -- Do stuff
end
```